# Unknown segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have two functions that are meant to calculate the span for a given set of numbers.

- Definition of the span: given a vector X, the span S[i] of X[i] is
  the maximum number of consecutive elements X[j] immediately preceding
  X[i] such that X[j] <= X[i].

  For example:
- X: 6 3 4 5 2
- S: 1 1 2 3 1

I'm trying to implement the algorithm in two ways. The first way is without using a stack ADT and the second is using a stack ADT; however, with both algorithms I'm getting a segmentation fault, and I can't figure out why! Any help would be much appreciated!

```
/*Stack.cpp
Implementation of the Stack class.
*/

#include "Stack.h"

....

vector<int> spans1(vector<int>& x) {

    int j = 0;
    vector<int> s;

    for( int i = 0; i < x.size()-1; i++ ) {
        j = 1;
        while( j <= i && x[i-j] <= x[j] )
            j++;
        s[i] = j;
    }

    return s;
}

vector<int> spans2(vector<int>& x) {
Stack t;
vector<int> span;
int j = 0;

for( int i = 0; i < x.size()-1; i++ ) {
    do {
        if( t.isEmpty() == true ) j = -1;
        else j = t.pop();  //removes the element at the top of the stack
    } 
    while( j != -1 && x[i] >= x[j] );

    span[i] = i - j;
    if( j != -1 ) t.push( j );
    t.push( i );
}

return span;
```

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
/*Main.cpp
Tests all functionality of the Stack class.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Stack.h"

int main() {
try {

    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(6);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(7);
    v.push_back(5);
    v.push_back(8);
    v.push_back(8);
    for( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) //output v
        cout << v[i] << " ";

    vector<int> sp1(spans1(v)); //My program crashes here
    vector<int> sp2(spans2(v)); //It crashes here also (if the previous line is                  
                                //commented out)

    for( int i = 0; i < sp1.size(); i++ ) //output sp1
        cout << "sp1: " << sp1[i] << " ";

    for( int i = 0; i < sp2.size(); i++ ) //output sp2
        cout << "sp2: " << sp2[i] << " ";

}
catch( int x ) {
    if( x = -1 )
        cout << "Access to empty stack";
}
}
```

Comment: Too much code! Please try to narrow it down. You can do that by running your program in a debugger. The debugger will stop at the location of the crash, and let you examine the function call stack. If the crash isn't in your code, you can walk up the call stack until you reach your code. There you can look at variables and examine their values. If nothing else, at least point out to us *where* in your code the crash happens,

Comment: Oh and by the way, your copy-assignment operator doesn't copy the `size` variable.

Comment: On the other hand, you don't actually *use* the `Stack` class anywhere in the `main` function or in the `spans1` function. Don't know about `spans2` though as you don't show it.

Comment: Oh! Good call! Thank you for that! I tried narrowing down the code posted. My program crashes whenever I call either spans1() or spans2().

Comment: @user2555471 - Why did you remove the `Stack` definition, i.e. `Stack.h`?  The answer(s) given have no context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various problem in the code. It is recommended to compile with all warning on always.

First: `Stack& Stack::operator=(const Stack& s)` has to return a value an don't, the fix is adding the line `return *this;` as the last line of the method (this is used for chaining assignment example `int a = b = c = 3;`

Second: `vector<int> spans2(vector<int>& x);` function is declared and called but no implemented.

Third and the real problem: the line `vector<int> s;` in **spans1** is declaring an **empty** vector, when you indexed like this `s[i] = j;` later it is an invalid access memory, the fix is change the bad line by `vector<int> s(x.size(), 0);` which initialize the vector with the same size than x and all elements with value 0.

Comment: Thank you! Adding vector<int> s(x.size(), 0); fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Your segmentation faults are most likely coming from an out of bounds write.
You have to make sure that the vectors are appropriately sized before you write into them.

```
vector<int> spans1(vector<int>& x) {

    int j = 0;
    vector<int> s; // < s is empty.

    for( int i = 0; i < x.size()-1; i++ ) {
        j = 1;
        while( j <= i && x[i-j] <= x[j] )
            j++;
        s[i] = j; // < You write to empty s here.
    }

    return s;
}
```

Try changing `vector<int> s;` to `vector<int> s(x.empty() ? 0 : x.size()-1);`.

`spans2` has a very similar problem.

Comment: The code has to check `x.empty()` before doing that.